Mental health and philosophy
How much can the impacts of mental health effects can be seen in philosophy i.e., are there actual Philosophers that are rumored or have been found to have actually had some sort of diagnosis or shown signs of it both prior to engagement in the field of philosophy or after, possibly during a great work of academic philosophy?
I wanted to know because usually people tend to have some sort of dissociation that occurs through out their life time and seem to have such an inquisitive and philosophical lens to look the world through.
One interesting case being Descartes:

While within, he had three dreams, and believed that a divine spirit
revealed to him a new philosophy. However, it is speculated that what
Descartes considered to be his second dream was actually an episode of
exploding head syndrome.
Descartes also saw very clearly that all truths were linked with one
another, so that finding a fundamental truth and proceeding with logic
would open the way to all science. Descartes discovered this basic
truth quite soon: his famous "I think, therefore I am."

I was just interested in the intersection between philosophy and mental illnesses such as DDD disorder or Schizophrenic type or even DID disorder?

Needs more focus: how could individuals within/without "philosophical engagement" be discriminated, when even pineapple pizza is a philosophical decision?

DID (originally MPD) was not diagnosed until 1970-s, Hacking has an interesting book about emergence of these diagnoses from a philosophical perspective, Rewriting the Soul. Psychiatrists Fitzgerald,  Gillberg and Ishisaka posthumously diagnosed Wittgenstein with autism, see a discussion of his philosophy of language in this light by Silva. Haidt in The  Righteous Mind diagnosed Bentham with Asperger's, also posthumously, Nietzsche and Kierkegaard suffered from severe depressions.

@RodolfoAP Okay, wow, first off what a crazy and hilarious world we live in. Personally, I am a proponent of pineapple pizza but to ban it truly says something about law and society. Regardless, are you saying that mental health disorders are a form of discrimination and therefore since philosophy is such an open and broad discipline will be hard to identify such cases? If so, how do you think I can focus my question to get a slightly satisfying answer, if not, get a discussion about this topic.

@user66697 I don't think that is necessarily right because philosophy is a discipline that has been dedicated to logic, logos and reasoning ever since the ancient times. I do not necessarily agree.
